# 1-1 function means simple zero?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a holomorphic function and $f(z)$ is 1-1.

If $f(z)$ has a zero at $z=x$,

then $x$ is a simple zero?

I guess this is simple fact, But I can't prove it, and I can't find related article.

Thanks!

Comment: @MartinR Why? I can not understand..

Comment: $f$ has a simple zero at $z$ if $f'(z) \ne 0$, that's how a simple zero is defined.

Comment: But non-zero means it is not identically 0, So it can be 0 at z.. am i wrong?

Comment: No. The referenced thread shows that if $f$ is one-to-one then $f'(z) \ne 0$ for *all* $z$ in the domain.

Comment: Ah I got it. Thanks. But it looks overkill... isn't it? :)

Answer (score 0):

If $f'(z_0)=\cdots=f^{(k-1)}(z_0)=0$ and $f^{(k)}(z_0)\ne 0$., then there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $z_0$, such that $f$ takes in $U\setminus\{z_0\}$ every value exactly $k$ times.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't follow this. Could you tell me more specific explanation?